# Why does this JSON array appear empty?

Tags: php, json, web-services

I am using a webservice to synchronize products from our distributor. As a first step, I have built a table to display the data to verify that everything is working properly. I have been able to successfully retrieve product descriptions using the following function:

```
function get_description($api_key, $item){
$url = 'http://www.stl-distribution.com/webservices/json/GetProductDescription.php';
$post_vars = 'api_key='.$api_key.'&item='.$item;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_vars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$return_data = curl_exec($ch);

$json_array = json_decode($return_data,true);
    return $json_array;
}
```

I am displaying the information using a foreach loop as follows:

```
      <table>
            <tr>
                    <th>ISBN</th>
                    <th>Description:</th>
                    <th>Categories:</th>
                    <th>Options:</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($product_ISBNs as $item) : ?>
            <tr>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $item[0]?></td>
                    <td class="center"><?php $item_description = get_description($api_key,$item[0]); echo $item_description['description'];?>
                    <td class="center"><?php $item_data = get_meta_data($api_key,$item[0]); echo $item_data['product_type']; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach?>
    </table>
```

While I have successfully been able to retrieve the description using the `get_description()` function, I consistently get the following error from the `get_meta_data()` function:

```
Notice: Undefined index: product_type in C:\xampp\htdocs\STLImport\view\user_form.php on line 21
```

The code for the `get_meta_data()` function is as followss:

```
function get_meta_data($api_key, $item){
$url = 'http://www.stl-distribution.com/webservices/json/GetProductMetaBasic.php';
$post_vars = 'api_key='.$api_key.'&item='.$item;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_vars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$return_data = curl_exec($ch);

$json_array = json_decode($return_data,true);
    return $json_array;
}
```

When I do a `print_r()` immediately before the `return $json_array;` statement I get the following error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [error] => "" not found ) )
```

According to our distributor's website, our requests are being sent and received. Every time I refresh the page my usage stats go up. So, it appears that either no data is being returned, or I am not referencing it correctly. I know that these products exist in the database because it is returning the description. Therefore, I must not be referencing it correctly but I can't find where my error is. I have tried referencing it using various combinations to no avail. The webservice documentation gives this example for how the data should be returned:

```
{
"9781434768513":
{
    "isbn13":"9781434768513",
    "isbn":"1434768511",
    "upc":"000000912992",
    "title":"Crazy Love",
    "subtitle":"Overwhelmed By A Relentless God",
    "contributor1":"Chan, Francis",
    "contributor2":"Yankoski, Danae",
    "contributor3":"",
    "vendor":"David C. Cook",
    "release_date":"20080430",
    "retail":"14.99",
    "binding":"Paperback",
    "product_type":"Books",
    "category1":"Christian Living",
    "category2":"",
    "category3":"",
    "grade_level_start":"",
    "grade_level_end":"",
    "inventory_updated":"20100825 11:25",
    "tn_available":993,
    "tn_onorder":240,
    "nv_available":735,
    "nv_onorder":0,
    "image_small":"http:\/\/www.stl-distribution.com\/covers\/7814\/sm-9781434768513.jpg",
    "image_medium":"http:\/\/www.stl-distribution.com\/covers\/7814\/md-9781434768513.jpg",
    "image_large":"http:\/\/www.stl-distribution.com\/covers\/7814\/lg-9781434768513.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Test your Request with the ´curl´ function in a terminal. Maybe this will give you more informations.

Comment: have you looked at the output string before doing `json_decode()`?

Comment: Agreed with @SDC. You are getting JSON back from the distributor, but for some reason your Item ID is failing to return anything.  Is your parameter name spelled correctly and in the correct case?

Comment: @SDC @J.D. Pace is `print_r($return_data)` the best way to view the output? I've tried that and received the error `[{"error":"\"\" not found"}] `

Comment: Okay. Now try `print $url`, to see the URL you're actually calling. That might show you the issue. If you can't see a problem with it, copy+paste it into your browser, see if it throws the same error via a direct call.

Comment: I am getting {"error":"api key was empty or invalid"} on both urls

Comment: @SDC the url is correct. When I paste it into the browser it downloads a file with the error `{"error":"api key was empty or invalid"}`. I have tried hardcoding the api key in  instead of using the variable with no change. The api key is the same one that is being used with success to call the description.

Comment: Just to verify that my api key is valid, I switched the url to the security test url. It verified my api key and sent the following response: `security test passed`

Comment: hmm... I'd suggest it's time to contact the API provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my `get_meta_data()` function had an error in it. My API provider informed me that this line

```
$post_vars = 'api_key='.$api_key.'&item='.$item;
```

Should have been

```
$post_vars = 'api_key='.$api_key.'&items='.$item;
```

Notice the addition of an 's'. So, `$json_array` appeared empty because it was empty. My other function worked because it did not require the 's' as `GetProductMetaBasic` did.

In addition, this line

```
<td class="center"><?php $item_data = get_meta_data($api_key,$item[0]); echo $item_data['product_type']; ?>
```

Should have been

```
<td class="center"><?php $item_data = get_meta_data($api_key,$item[0]); echo $item_data[$item[0]]['product_type']; ?></td>
```

because, as the sample data implied, the array was multidimensional. The desired value (`product_type`) was contained within the `$item[0]` array. Therefore, `$item_data['product_type']` did not exist.